# Prove that the set $\{ n: n \in \mathbb{N} > 10\}$ is denumerable.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am pretty sure it is denumerable but I can't figure out how to prove it

Comment: To prove that a set $A$ is denumerable, you need to explain a bijection between $A$ and $\mathbb{Z}$.  In other words, you need to demonstrate a mapping that takes each element of $A$ to a unique integer, and each integer to a unique element of $A$.  Have you tried doing this?

Comment: It's been over a year since I've taken this course and unfortunately I don't remember how to do that. I got an incomplete due to having surgery and now I'm back to finish and the professor took a sebatical so she is unavailable to offer assistance

Comment: $n \mapsto n-10$

Comment: what fractal1729 is saying is that a set is denumerable if it's countably infinite. That is if $||A||= \aleph_0$. You can show that by finding a bijection between one set and another that is also $\aleph_0$. So is $\mathbb N$, and can you find a bijection $g: A \to \mathbb N$?

Comment: You apparently mean $\{ n: n \in \mathbb{N}, n > 10\}$. What you wrote is imprecise in this form, and its intended meaning is unclear: $\{ n: n \in \mathbb{N} > 10\}$. (This is so, despite that everyone here already got the intended meaning, you should strive to be precise in your language anyway :)

Comment: I actually did a copy and paste from the assignment that was given. My apologies

Answer (score 3):

$$
1\leftrightarrow 11\\
2\leftrightarrow 12\\
3\leftrightarrow 13\\
4\leftrightarrow 14\\
5\leftrightarrow 15\\
6\leftrightarrow 16\\
7\leftrightarrow 17\\
\vdots
$$

Comment: While you're at it, why not also add the explicit bijection $n\mapsto n+10$?